# Must declare the scalar variable "@tglMasukKerja"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created sql scheduler that will execute a store procedure. That scheduler is running well but suddenly it's give me an error yesterday.

> Must declare the scalar variable "@tglMasukKerja".

here is my procedure code :

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @NIK nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @empID nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @empName varchar(100)
DECLARE @email nvarchar(150)
DECLARE @spvID varchar(50)
DECLARE @jabatan nvarchar(150)
DECLARE @dept nvarchar(150)
DECLARE @gol nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @tglMasukKerja(date)
DECLARE @divisi nvarchar(50)
```

Please tell me where is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: Try to execute `DECLARE @tglMasukKerja(date)`. You get: _"Incorrect syntax near '('."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare a variable in your code this way:

```
DECLARE @tglMasukKerja(date)
```

This isn't correct. Just declare it this way:

```
DECLARE @tglMasukKerja date
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Write it like that:

```
DECLARE @tglMasukKerja Date
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! I didn't see it.